# Ensure Variable Initialization C#

Tags: c#, .net, variables, instance-variables

Consider this code:

```
public string Variable1 { get; set;}
public int Variable2 { get; set;}

public void Function()
{
 // Has been Variable1 Initialized?
}
```

Inside the function, I want to know if a value has been sent to Variable1 & Variable2, prior to the function call,

**even if the DEFAULT values have been sent, that's ok (null for string & 0 for int)**

Comment: I think the meta-answer here is "so don't do that". Make sure all variables are initialized in the constructor.

Comment: What if I have two functions. F1 & F2, each using both Variables. But for F1 I must be sure that the caller of the function has set values to the variables, even if those are null. For the F2 I don't care, I don't want to force him to send something in the constructor!

Comment: if for F1 you need the *caller* to have set the variables, why don't you just pass them as arguments to F1?

Comment: It's about Clean Code, Cohesion, the fact that I use Variable1 & Variable2 for multiple other functions, but only in some parts I want to throw an exception if they haven't been initialized and so on...

Comment: If you need Variable1 and Variable2 to be set for F1 to run, your object is in an inconsistent state if they aren't. So you have to set them before the object is ready for use. Maybe you want to decompose your object to split out the requirements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using a simple wrapper like this:

```
public struct AssignableProperty<T>
{
    private T _value;

    public T Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            WasAssigned = true;
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    public bool WasAssigned { get; private set; }

    public static implicit operator AssignableProperty<T>(T data)
    {
        return new AssignableProperty<T>() { Value = data };
    }

    public static bool operator ==(AssignableProperty<T> initial, T data)
    {
        return initial.Value.Equals(data);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(AssignableProperty<T> initial, T data)
    {
        return !initial.Value.Equals(data);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then your class'll look like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public AssignableProperty<string> Variable1 { get; set; }
    public AssignableProperty<int> Variable2 { get; set; }

    public void Function()
    {
        if(Variable1.WasAssigned&&Variable2.WasAssigned)
            //do stuff
    }
}
```

You can go further and add throw Exception or contract to getter, so if somebody'll try to access uninitialized value it'll throw an exception or show you warning

Comment: The downside with this approach is you now have to say `instance.Variable1.Value = "something"` in order to set the property.

Comment: @Sean You're right, be it saves you the verbosity and repetition everywhere you want a flag.

Comment: @Sean nope, AFAIK you can override cast and comparison operators so that you can make a simple assignement like Variable1="something" and comparison with initial type (T) won't be a pain. What you really lack is memory

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy - I know, but you didn't mention that in the answer!

Comment: I like it. But I wouldn't allow external "forces" to set 'WasAssigned'

Comment: Nifty little solution

Comment: @Noel yes unless you make `WasAssigned` setter private

Comment: @Sean Edited my answer and also you, guys, are absolutely right about WasAssigned, my fault

Comment: unfortunately, your code doesn't work. It fails at Variable1.WasAssigned (NullReferenceException). The requirement is that Variable1 can be null, it's just that the null must be assigned before calling the Function ;) That's the tricky part.

Comment: @Proka yeah, fixed it. Use struct instead if class and it'll be OK

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I have accepted your solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Some basics about default value in C#:**

When an instance of a class (or struct) is created, all fields are initialized to their respective default value.

For reference types, it will be `null`. For value types, it will be equivalent to `0`. This is easily explains as the memory management ensures that new allocated memory is initialized to 0x0 bytes.

Auto-properties hide the generated field, but there is one. So the same rules apply.

**Now to answer your question**, the best way to make sure that values are initialized is to make a constructor with one parameter for each field/property and to hide the default constructor with no parameters:

```
public Yourtype(String param1, Int32 param2)
{
    this.Variable1 = param1;
    this.Variable2 = param2;
}

private Yourtype() { }
```

Other alternatives is described in @Sean and @Alex answers if only a subset of properties/fields needs to be initialized/checked. But this hides some overhead (one `bool` for each property/field and some indirection).

Answer (score 0):

For the reference types you'll need to add a flag:

```
string m_Variable1;
bool m_IsVariable1Set;

public string Variable1
{
  get{return m_Variable1;}
  set{m_IsVariable1Set = true; m_Variable1 = value;}
}
```

For the value types you can use a nullable value

```
int? m_Variable2;

int Variable2
{
  get{return m_Variable2.GetValueOrDefault();}
  set{m_Variable2 = value;}
}
```

Which you can then check to see if it's been set by using `m_Variable2.HasValue`.

Answer (score -2):

Well you can simply do a check on both variables to see if they have any value assigned to them in your function

```
public void Function()
{

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Variable1) && Variable2 ==0 )
    {
      // Variables are not assigned
    }

}
```

Comment: And if `Variable1` is `null`, does that mean someone initialized the value or not?

Comment: If you want to check for a default value of a Type at runtime you should use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281161/how-to-get-the-default-value-of-a-type-if-the-type-is-only-known-as-system-type

Comment: I don't want to check for a default value. I want to check if prior to the function call, someone has sent something to the var, even if that's NULL or zero or whatever default value for each type.